# Parallelizing while loop with two statements (Floyd cycle detection algorithm)

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, performance, openmp

I'll tried to *parallelize* the following *simple* `while` loop into two threads with **OpenMP** *(my first walking attempts with this technology)*. I've tried to use both, `sections` and `tasks`. Despite I got it to get split into two threads and yielding a correct result, the *performance* was inacceptable slow.

```
while ( tortoise != hare ) {
    tortoise = f ( tortoise );
    hare = f ( f ( hare ) );
}
```

**Note:** `f` is a `const &` to a function object (i.e. it has an `T operator()(const T &r)`)

The `operator()` is implemented as following (`d` is a member variable of the *function object*):

```
T operator() ( const T &r ) const {
    return ( ( r % d ) * 10 );
}
```

My first thoughts have been the overhead of creating the threads. So I created the `team` at the very beginning of the enclosing function (which itself is only called once, while the `while`-loop above itself can have a lot of iterations (it is part of the [*Floyd cycle detection algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare)).

*I've omitted here all my `#pragma omp ...` attempts since all of them resulted in bad performance.*

#### Edit:

Based on **@templatetypedef**'s answer I tried *Brent's algorithm*. Since I need to *inject* some calculations on *Floyd's* second and third `while`-loop *(building a digits array of the pre-cycle and the cyclic values, as well as calculating a polynom using the Horner scheme)* *Brent* offers me no points to add this code. Therefore I would prefer *Floyd*. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/velnias75/rational/blob/7f92e2240cdaee0351311be0c029dd7387b807fe/src/rational/rational.h).

Comment: How is `f` implemented? Do you really think that multithreading will speed this up, given that each thread would basically be calling f and then doing a ton of work to sync up with the other thread?

Comment: @templatetypedef since I think the two statements can be processed in parallel I want to give it a try on a multicore CPU. I've added the implementation of  `T operator()(const T &r)` to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the code you're trying to parallelize just doesn't parallelize well. Think of it this way: each thread needs to do essentially a dozen or so arithmetic operations to advance its pointer, but then needs to synchronize with the other thread to confirm that the values aren't the same and can't make any partial progress until both threads complete. The cost of simply locking or unlocking a mutex is [about 17ns](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html), which is probably about how long it takes to evaluate one of the tortoise or hare steps. As a result, each thread probably ends up doing just about the same amount of work as a single loop iteration would - and probably a lot more - so I seriously doubt that you'll get a speedup this way.

Now, what might work would be to use an algorithm like Brent's cycle-finding algorithm, which makes fewer comparisons than Floyd's algorithm and generally converges faster. That would most likely get you to find the cycle a lot faster.

Comment: Ok, so my assumption of the overhead could be right. I'll already tried the *Brent algorithm*, but I had a problem to *inject* some additional code as I did in *Floyd's* second and third `while`. But if parallelizing of *Brent* could be more promising. I have to try to understand that variant or if the performance gain is so huge, even not *injecting* my code, but doing it afterwards. - I'll wait for some more ideas else I will accept your answer.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_parallel_algorithms to understand why any attempt to get significant parallel speedup of Floyd's algorithm is doomed, even on a ideal theoretical machine.  Both work and span for cycle detection are going to be proportional to the cycle length, hence their quotient will be O(1).